# I am looking for a way in Azure DevOps to have a good overview of the status of my A/B tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Since the process of one A/B test usually takes multiple sprints I would like to add another board in which I can add the A/B tests (as F.E. features). User stories for one sprint can then be added to a specific sprint for my team (which consists of a few specialists and a developer). This way I am able to overview the status (research phase, test , code writing, running, analysis, etc.) of all tests in one overview. I have not been able to find out how this is possiblie within Azure Devops, or if there is a work around. Can anyone help me?

My team also works in projects other than A/B tests, which means we cannot use the boards section.
Unless there is a hidden way to add another board to a team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [Copy or clone a work item](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbacklogs%2Fcopy-clone-work-items%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dbrowser%23copy-or-clone-a-work-item&data=04%7C01%7Cv-shuqiji%40microsoft.com%7C1a229215b67242d6cb7208d9fdb1a3b9%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637819761785524552%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=ytNa6wxKZOYxf%2Fz%2F0gaioeXu2fx2INt5N%2Fczz%2FPPrRk%3D&reserved=0) to add the user stories or tests to a new boards. Open the user story you want to clone, then click Create copy of work item and choose whether to include exist links, attachments and child work items. After creating, change the Area and Iteration to your target boards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update**

In Azure DevOps you can only create boards by creating a team. The team board is created as a side-effect of creating the team. Please refer to [Manage and configure team tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) and [Configure and customize Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/configure-customize?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)for details.

After creating and configuring a new team, you could see the boards in the dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: @Esther Montijn is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let me know whether the answers below can help you and feel free to comment~ Just a remind to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem however lays partly in the fact that I can't add another board to my team

Comment: @Esther Montijn I have update the answer, please check is that helpful.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I think this just means I am not able to create another board for the same team, but I might be able to use this as a work around

Comment: @Esther Montijn, could you please [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to mark it as an answer?